# How to export Vonage AI call logs to Excel

Tags: vonage

I am currently using Vonage AI studio to create a automated AI chatbot. I want to be able to export the call logs from this studio into Excel. I understand there is an import function, but I want to be able to export call logs automatically as customers use the service live. How can I do this?